# Getting error "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've written one function with Flow collector which is as shown below,

```
private fun callSocket(
        eventEmmit: String,
        eventOn: String,
        request: JSONObject
    ): Flow<SocketCallback<JSONObject>> =
        flow {
            try {
                if (socket.connected()) {
                    var response = JSONObject()
                    Log.e("EMIT", JSONObject(Gson().toJson(request)).toString())

                    socket.on(
                        eventOn
                    ) { args ->
                        response = args[0] as JSONObject
                        Log.e("ON", response.toString())
                        **this.emit(SocketCallback.OnSuccess(response))**
                    }.emit(
                        eventEmmit,
                        request
                    )
                    emit(SocketCallback.OnSuccess(response))
                } else {
                    Log.e("SOCKET_ERROR", "Socket connection failed")
                    emit(SocketCallback.OnError("Socket connection failed"))
                }
            } catch (e: SocketException) {
                emit(SocketCallback.OnError(e.toString()))
            }
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

But when I write **this.emit(SocketCallback.OnSuccess(response))**(enclosed in ** in code) in **on** method it shows me the error "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body".

Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OnSuccess method is suspended method?

Comment: It is a method of sealed class and it is for callback which will be returned whenever I get on from socket. @JinalPatel

Comment: @KaranMehta Can you add the `on` function code in the question?

Comment: It is already there @ArpitShukla, on is an event/callback that we get when we start the socket. I'm converting the response in JSONObject and then want to return it every time I receive callback in socket.on().

Comment: Yeah but can you add the function signature of `on` method? What arguments does it take and what does it return?

Comment: It only takes one argument which is event name in string.

Comment: From what it seems, it takes more than one argument. The lambda should also be part of the arguments. Can you add the signature?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to emit events to `flow` outside of `coroutineScope`. `socket.on()` function probably has signature:

```
fun on(ev: String, block: (args: String) -> Unit) {

}
```

in that case, inside lambda `block: (args: String) -> Unit)` you are outside of scope and you can not invoke suspending functions.

You have only 2 solutions:

1. Every time new event approach - create new coroutine with coroutine builder `launch`:

```
socket.on(
    eventOn
) { args ->
    response = args[0] as JSONObject
    Log.e("ON", response.toString())
    launch {
        emit(SocketCallback.OnSuccess(response))
    }
}.emit(
    eventEmmit,
    request
)
```

2. Use [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) to avoid creation of new coroutine on each event. Please check especially [this](https://elizarov.medium.com/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf) post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it by using the **CallBackFlow**

```
private fun callOnSocket(
        eventOn: String
    ): Flow<SocketCallback<JSONObject>> =
        callbackFlow<SocketCallback<JSONObject>> {
            try {
                if (socket.connected()) {
                    Log.e("ON", "Started")
                    var response = JSONObject()
                    socket.on(
                        eventOn
                    ) {
                        response = it[0] as JSONObject
                        Log.e("ON", response.toString())
                        trySend(SocketCallback.OnSuccess(response))
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("SOCKET_ERROR", "Socket connection failed")
                    trySend(SocketCallback.OnError("Socket connection failed"))
                }
            } catch (e: SocketException) {
                trySend(SocketCallback.OnError("Socket connection failed"))
            }
            awaitClose { cancel() }
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Comment: The purpose of `awaitClose` is to unregister your listener so you don't leak it, not to cancel the flow, which is already completed at this point.